# IOS TableView - RegisterClass does not display content

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I've just started learning some IOS stuff and I'm using Swift to code my app in. I've come across a problem with my table views where, for some reason, they don't seem to be displaying the content in my table view.

In my view controller that contains the TableView I have in the `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: textCellIdentifier)
```

Going by all of the resource that I have seen, they seem to suggest this is what you need to allow your table view to display list items of type UITableViewCell. When I run my program, nothing seems to appear in my tableView object. I found a tutorial somewhere where they were writing it a bit differently. Rather than using `registerClass` they had:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self
```

I replaced the `registerClass` method with this and it seems to be working perfectly fine. Can anyone explain why my `registerClass` method doesn't work and what this other solution has done to make it work? Is this bad practise in IOS assigning values like this with view objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line you have is just telling the table which class of cells to use (in this case `UITableViewCell`). The other lines (setting the datasource and delegate) tell the table where to get their data from and who to notify when something changes (like when someone clicks on a cell).

So you will need to have all three lines. You can do some/all of this in Storyboard so that is why some tutorials may not contain all of that code.

For example, if you are using static or prototyped cells in storyboard you would not include the `registerClass`. Likewise, if you draw the tableview to your class in storyboard and set its `dataSource` and `delegate` that way you would not include those setters.

To get data displaying on your table you need to assign it a data source (like in your example) then implement:

[tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:)
- Tells the table how many rows there should be (in a given section)

[tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)
- Gives the table an actual cell to present (of the type you registered above)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I missed the dataSource and delegate outlets in the storyboard. Always seems to be something hidden from you in these tutorials! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @StuartRobertson, yes, there does. One of the disadvantages of storyboards too IMO is they are a bit hard sometimes to know what is going since you need to dig around on it trying to figure out where/if something is set. Glad it is working!

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong : `registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: textCellIdentifier)`<-- what this does is that is : *ties* a vanilla cellIdentifier to a customClass and then appends/registers it to the tableView? Later we use that identifier ie **not** the class to dequeue because we can't dequeue classes as we only have 1 class, yet we may have different kinds of cells of the same class.

Comment: @honey, Yes to most of it. You only have one class, but will end up having many instances of that class (these are the cells). The identifier is used since the cells are placed into buckets and pulled out when requested (reused), to prevent creating a brand new cell every time. You _can_ have multiple instances of the same class without the identifier. The identifier is required for optimization, Apple could have done this without one. But you have the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

`registerClass, forCellReuseIdentifier` does exactly that, every time a new cell is needed, it is instantiated from the class you registered with this method.

`self.tableView.dataSource = self` tells `self.tableView` that it needs to use `self` for the dataSource methods (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/UITableViewDataSource) which return things like the number of sections, number of rows, etc.

Without supplying a `dataSource` to a `tableView`, it will always be empty (because it doesn't know the number of sections, rows, headers, footers, etc, to display, so it will display 0).

Comment: so if due to height limitation only 8 rows can be seen from our tableView, the register would only happen 8 times?

Comment: @Honey - no, the `registerClass` is called manually, by you, likely once per each identifier that you are using. If your tableView can only show 8 rows, and all those rows use the same reuseIdentifier, then the class specified in your call to `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier` will be instantiated 8 times (and maybe one or two more for preparing adjacent, offscreen UITableViewCells)

Comment: so assuming our code is same as the OP, register will be called once. but UITableViewCell will be called 8 times. right?

Comment: Yes, maybe 9 depending on the exact dimensions of the `UITableView` and the `UITableViewCell`'s